# ARC (Authenticated Received Chain) on Exchange 2013?

Tags: linux, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013

After a successfully implementation of [OpenARC](https://github.com/trusteddomainproject/OpenARC) on a Linux enviroment I have now started to look at the possibility to implement it on a Exchange environment.

I am fully aware that the [draft](http://arc-spec.org) is subject to change, but providers like Google has already implemented it. Therefore, I would like to deploy it on a Exchange 2013 server.

So my question is, what is the best approach to deploy ARC (Authenticated Received Chain) on a Exchange 2013 environment? Is it even possible yet?
Or should I relay the mails throu another server which signs the messages with the ARC header and DKIM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did "solve" it by route emails via a Linux server instead, configured with postfix, amavisd-new (for DKIM signing) and openARC.

The emails is signed correctly and valid. I consider this the "solution" for now until Microsoft has implemented it in Exchange Server.

Answer (score 2):

In On-premise Exchange, we can use [**SPF, DKIM and DMARC**](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35595.on-premises-exchange-dkim-and-dmarc-setup.aspx) to prevent spoofing message. No official document about ARC with On-premise Exchange for now.

ARC can be used in Office 365. Refer to:
[How antispoofing protection works in Office 365](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tzink/2016/02/23/how-antispoofing-protection-works-in-office-365/)

Comment: Alright, so do you recommend that I do the signing on a separate server then? If so, provide that in the answer so I can mark your question as an asnwer